# IBAction did not work

Tags: ios, uiview, mapbox-gl

I am implementing the custom annotation for map in ios. I added one button to show location's detailed information. But the IBAction did not work in my custom view because the MapView is covering up to my custom view. Is there a way to trigger IBAction under a view.
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj8oK.png)

```
-(MGLAnnotationView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation { 
    [self.vwCustomAnnotation.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.vwCustomAnnotation];
    self.vwCustomAnnotation.centerOffset = CGVectorMake(0, -self.vwCustomAnnotation.frame.size.height/2); 
    return self.vwCustomAnnotation; 
}
```

Comment: Ei Ei  Tun bring your custom view above map view and when you are done with your action just hide that custom view.

Comment: I used [self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:self.vwCustomAnnotation]. But it did not work and the mapview is still covering my custom view.

Comment: Show some code and error log.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @TusharSharma - 
`code`
-(MGLAnnotationView *)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MGLAnnotation>)annotation {
    [self.vwCustomAnnotation.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.vwCustomAnnotation];
    self.vwCustomAnnotation.centerOffset = CGVectorMake(0, -self.vwCustomAnnotation.frame.size.height/2);
    return self.vwCustomAnnotation;
}

Comment: I used Map SDK from mapbox